# Unable to click in Windows install of 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, mouse

I just installed ubuntu 12.04 through windows in order to try it out. My mouse can move (real choppy at first, but smooths out) but can never click. Keyboard also unresponsive. Both are wireless, usb and work fine in windows.

Any solutions? Will they work in a full install?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "through windows"? Virtual machine or wubi?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking virtual machine, you can't really rely on the experience. Wubi however should behave just as a "full" install. Have you tried looking for drivers etc.? Try System settings -> Additional Drivers or check online directly querying for your product.